# Smooth varieties in a Hilbert scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

For a given Hilbert polynomial $P$, consider the Hilbert scheme $\text{Hilb}_P (\mathbb P^n)$.
If it is not empty, then does it contain a smooth variety?

Here $\text{Hilb}_P (\mathbb P^n)$ is regarded as the collection of  closed subschemes of $\mathbb P^n$  whose Hilbert polynomial is $P$.

Comment: What do you mean by "contain"?  As an irreducible component?

Comment: In this question, $\text{Hilb}_P (\mathbb P^n)$ is regarded as the set of  closed subschemes of $\mathbb P^n$  whose Hilbert polynomial is $P$.

Comment: I understand the question to mean: is there a point $p \in \operatorname{Hilb}_P \mathbf P^n$ such that the closed subscheme $Z_p \subset \mathbf P^n$ corresponding to the point $p$ is a smooth variety? (In which case, one needs to specify whether "variety" includes "connected".)